# Keras EarlyStopping is not recognized

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am using Early Stopping in my U-net model but it is raising error

```
File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    earlystopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=15, verbose=1, mode='auto', baseline=None, restore_best_weights=False)
NameError: name 'EarlyStopping' is not defined
```

However Keras callback function is working well

I cannot understand where the problem is?
any help is acknowledged.

```
from model import *
from data import *

data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=0.2,
                width_shift_range=0.05,
                height_shift_range=0.05,
                shear_range=0.05,
                zoom_range=0.05,
                horizontal_flip=True,
                fill_mode='nearest')
myGene = trainGenerator(2,'data/membrane/train','image','label',data_gen_args,save_to_dir = None)

model = unet()
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('unet_membrane.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
earlystopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=15, verbose=1, mode='auto', baseline=None, restore_best_weights=False)
model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=300,epochs=200,callbacks=[model_checkpoint, earlystopper])

testGene = testGenerator("data/membrane/test")
results = model.predict_generator(testGene,86,verbose=1)
saveResult("data/membrane/test",results)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are importing it right?
`from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping`
[Colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qyys9dVtVmFMoEnzWwa2ur49gf8LMIYX)

Answer (score 10):

You have to import classes before using them:

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
```

Since you are using `from something import *`, it is possible that the imports from those modules are leaking into the current module, so it might error for some classes but not for others.

As a good practice, always import in the same file.

Comment: Thank you I missed importing EarlyStopping

Comment: So you can just say no .. no problem